# adding the same message for several files in linux

Tags: linux, shell, cat

I´ve written the line command this, but it doesn´t work

```
cat fich?.txt < hi, adding message for several files
```

I´ve got the following files

fich1.txt
fich2.txt
fich3.txt
fich4.txt
fich5.txt
fich6.txt

Comment: Are you creating the files or modifying them?

Comment: You most likely don't have a file named `hi,` for the shell to redirect input from, nor files named `adding`, `message`, `for`, `several` or `files` for `cat` to read. I suspect you get a "bash: hi, : no such file or directory" sort of message given that command; and `cat` will never even be started. What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for f in fich?.txt; do
  cat message.txt >>$f
done
```

This will add (append) the contents of the file `message.txt` to all files matching the shell globbing pattern `fich?.txt`.  If you want to be more strict and only match the specific files that you mentioned, use the pattern `fich[1-6].txt`.

To add something to the beginning of each file, do this:

```
for f in fich?.txt; do
  tmpfile=$( mktemp XXXXX )
  cat message.txt $f >$tmpfile
  mv $tmpfile $f
done
```

No catching of errors is happening here, so it's not fool-proof or super safe.

Answer (score 0):

Different approach - inserts the new content at the beginning of the file

```
for f in fich*.txt; do 
    sed --in-place '1 ihi, adding message for several files' "$f"; 
done
```